# Optimize Aggregate Query MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, optimization, mongodb-query, query-optimization

I am creating a leaderboard to rank users on multiple different activities. There are roughly 140 different activities that users will need to be ranked on. For brevity, here is an example of what my user data looks like:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$binary": {
      "base64": "pADjWT71RgKLeSo5bxm2GQ==",
      "subType": "04"
    }
  },
  "weaponMasteryLevels": {
    "SCYTHE": 3,
    "AXE": 46,
    "STAFF": 14,
    "SWORD": 67
  },
  "statistics": {
    "SUCCESSFUL_TRIALS": 35288,
    "PLAYER_KILLS": 48157
  },
  "mobKills": {
    "LAYER_1": 41769,
    "LAYER_3": 3895,
    "LAYER_4": 49093,
    "LAYER_2": 69889,
    "NONE": 69623,
    "LAYER_5": 75124
  }
}
```

In this example, I would like to rank users from highest to lowest on the weaponMasteryLevels, statistics & mobKills subfields. For example, there should be a separate ranking for mobKills.LAYER_1, mobKills.LAYER_2, mobKills.LAYER_3, etc...

That said, I have written some java code using the sync driver to perform an aggregate query that will pull and sort the data I need:

```
// "field" variable is equal to whatever field I am ranking at the moment (ie: mobkills.LAYER_1)
AggregateIterable<Document> aggregate = registry.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                Aggregates.sort(Sorts.descending(field)),
                Aggregates.project(Projections.include("_id", field)) 
        )).batchSize(MAX_RESULTS + 1)
```

This works, but is a bit slow for my liking. Using some generated data, it takes roughly 1000 - 2000ms to run this aggregate query per field, for around 15,000 users.

What would be some recommended ways to optimize my query?

NOTE: I have tried creating indices for each field, but I run into 2 issues:

1. The query doesn't seem to be running much faster, I suspect that I'm doing something wrong.
2. The number of fields I need to sort on (140) exceeds the maximum amount of indices that MongoDB allows (64), therefore, I cannot create an index for each field.

Comment: Consider saving the rank per layers per user in another collection. This will allow you to get it fast